# How to have a NULL instead of No Value from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I had a query like:

```
SELECT ISNULL(S.Name+'.'+T.Name,'Table Not Found')
FROM DataProfile.Tables T
INNER JOIN DataProfile.Schemas S ON T.schemaId=S.Id
WHERE S.Name+'.'+T.Name=@TableName
```

Then I tried

```
IIF(LEN(S.Name+'.'+T.Name)>0,S.Name+'.'+T.Name,NULL)
```

But when it doesn't find the named table returns not output, Value or Null value or anything I can work on.
This is going to be used as a crosscheck.
Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: By concatenating `var1+'.'+var2`, that value will always be at least `.`, so it will never be `null` nor a length of 0. You should check the `null` status of each field independently.

Comment: As long as its not var for sure it returns no value! :/ @gmiley

Comment: @gmiley - that is not correct, if either `var1` or `var2` is `null` concatenating will result in `null`

Comment: @El.Ham: There is a difference between `No rows returned` and value returned as `NULL`. User `LEFT JOIN` instead

Comment: I should add that it is dependent upon how the database is set up. It could be set to have concatenated nulls not be null. See `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`.

Comment: either together or individually they have NO VALUE. please pay attention to what i exactly asked.tnx @gmiley

Comment: @zarruq Im going to return 'Name of Found Table'/'Table Not Found'  row when this query returns nothing. even i tried subqueries and etc.

Comment: Try `OUTER JOIN` (either left or right) on main table. Rows will be returned in that case. Then if the row is null, you can use `ISNULL`, 'IIF', `coalesce` etc

Comment: @gmiley CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is ON by default in SQL Server 2008 and and can't be changed in later versions of SQL Server. Note BOL: 
> In a future version of SQL Server CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Comment: You could check [`@@RowCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql) to determine whether the query returned a row.

Comment: This is a well written question. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for those who payed attention to what I exactly asked and for their responses.
Here the way I tried:

```
DECLARE @Check NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'TABLE DOES NOT FOUND'

SELECT @Check= S.Name + '.' + T.Name
FROM DataProfile.Tables T
INNER JOIN DataProfile.Schemas S ON T.schemaId=S.Id
WHERE S.Name+'.'+T.Name=@TableName

SELECT @CHECK
```

And That Worked for me

Comment: Good and useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

this will always return a row:

```
select v.TableName, ISNULL(found.result, 'not found') result
from (values(@TableName))v(TableName)
    outer apply (
        select CAST('found' as nvarchar(11)) result
        from DataProfile.Tables T
            join  DataProfile.Schemas S ON T.schemaId=S.Id
        where S.Name+'.'+T.Name=v.TableName
    )found
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (LEN(S.Name + '.' + T.Name))> 1 THEN S.Name + '.' + T.Name ELSE NULL END
```

So you qry will look like

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN (LEN(S.Name + '.' + T.Name))> 1 THEN 
          S.Name + '.' + T.Name 
       ELSE 
          NULL -- Here use any expresion which you want
       END
FROM DataProfile.Tables T
INNER JOIN DataProfile.Schemas S ON T.schemaId=S.Id
WHERE S.Name+'.'+T.Name=@TableName
```

Here you are using ISNULL(S.Name+'.'+T.Name,'Table Not Found') which never return false part due to if S.Name and T.Name both are null then still that value will be '.'

Comment: as long as there is nothing returned it doesnt work. i did it.tnx so much for ur response

Comment: @El.Ham, ow you did it

Comment: sorry I was forget to use > 1, I updated. I was Added > 0

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way:

```
with table_qry as
(
    select S.Name as SName, T.Name as TName
    from DataProfile.Tables T
    inner join DataProfile.Schemas S 
    on T.SchemaId = S.Id
    where S.Name+'.'+T.Name = @TableName
)
select case when (select count(1) from table_qry) > 0 then
    SName+'.'+TName else 'Table Not Found' end as TableName
from table_qry;
```

There are more elegant ways of doing it, but this should work just fine for you.